# Writing failure: A provided name contains an illegal character. Error while saving R data into Stata format

Tags: r, stata, r-haven

I am using haven package to write the R dataset into Stata format.

This is the error I am getting.

`write_dta(road_panel, "road_panel.dta", version = 14, label = attr(data,"label"))`

`Error in write_dta_(data, normalizePath(path, mustWork = FALSE), version = stata_file_format(version),  :  Writing failure: A provided name contains an illegal character.`

I also tried a slightly different code but its the same.

```
`write_dta(road_panel, "road_panel_stata.dta")
```

`Error in write_dta_(data, normalizePath(path, mustWork = FALSE), version = stata_file_format(version),  :  Writing failure: A provided name contains an illegal character.`

How can I successfully export the data into Stata format?

The output of names(road_panel):

[149] "road_comp_date_new_year_final"      "road_comp_date_upg_year_final"      "road_comp_date_stip_new_year_final" "road_comp_date_stip_upg_year_final"
[153] "year"

Comment: Hi Fuser. What output do you get with `names(road_panel)`?

Comment: Hard to say. Note that Stata 14 supports Unicode. Have you any idea what the character might be? No doubt a stupid question, but equally without more details, an answer is hard. The code might be giving up on the first of several awkward characters.

Comment: I have 153 variables with long names. I edit the question with the output of names(road_panel).

Comment: It looks like variable 2 and variable 122 contains a period : `"shrid.x"` and `"shrid.y"`, which I don't think is legal in Stata. Also, my understanding is that variable names must have a maximum of 32 characters, which your last variable name exceeds. Perhaps rename these 3 and try again?

Comment: Yeah, it worked by replacing ".". Thanks a lot, Allan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple fix could be to use `foreign::write.dta`. It will replace all variable names with `x.y` to `x_y`:

```
library(foreign)
write.dta(road_panel, "road_panel_stata.dta")
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that want to use `haven`. You can simply rename variables removing the illegal character `.`

Something like this should work

```
names(road_panel) <- str_replace_all(names(road_panel), pattern = "\\.", replacement = "_"))) # to replace illegal character

write_dta(road_panel, "road_panel_stata.dta")# to save data
```